# JQuery DatePicker only shows one date

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datepicker, disabled-control

I have a date picker on a form, built with Knockout JS.
It was working until recently but now it is not.

When you click on the icon to open the date picker, it only shows one month: June 2021, and won't let you even navigate away from that month. This is true for all the date fields on the form.

Here's a screen shot:[image: Screen shot of error]

This happens in Google Chrome and Firefox, latest versions of each.
Using Firebug in Firefox, I can see there are no JavaScript errors on the page.

Here's the HTML shown in Firebug for two of the table rows, the one starting 'Start Date' and the one starting 'Entries Open':

```
<tr>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <td data-bind="text: niceDate(StartDate())">05-03-2016 00:00:00</td>
    <th>Finish Date</th>
    <td data-bind="text: niceDate(FinishDate())">06-03-2016 00:00:00</td>
</tr>

<tr class="entries-open">
    <th>
        <label>Entries Open</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input id="dp1452774306035" maxlength="9" size="10" name="ko_unique_20" class="jq-date hasDatepicker" data-bind="value: niceDate(EntriesOpen()), uniqueName: true" data-field="EntriesOpen" type="text">
    <img title="..." alt="..." src="/asp-net/protected/events/admin/calendar_icon.gif" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></td>
    <th>
        <label>Late Entry Surcharge Date</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input id="dp1452774306036" maxlength="9" size="10" name="ko_unique_21" class="jq-date hasDatepicker" data-bind="value: niceDate(EntriesClose()), uniqueName: true" data-field="EntriesClose" type="text">
    <img title="..." alt="..." src="/asp-net/protected/events/admin/calendar_icon.gif" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></td>
</tr>
```

The JSON for Knockout JS with the dates looks like this:

```
"StartDate": "2016-03-18T00:00:00",
"FinishDate": "2016-03-20T00:00:00",
"BallotDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
"EntriesOpen": "2016-02-12T00:00:00",
"EntriesClose": "2016-03-08T00:00:00",
```

**[Edit]**

1. For confirmation, this is the jQuery UI date picker. I was using
   version 1.8.9 but I have tried upgrading to jQuery UI 1.11.4 but
   this has not resolved it. I'm using jQuery 1.6.1. Not the most up-to-date version, but this would take much more work to update as it is used site wide.
2. I've tried different date formats - as well as the original
   "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss", I have also tried :

   - "DD-MM-YYYY"
   - "DD/MM/YYYY"
   - "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
   - Repeated for US-style "MM-DD-YYYY" dates
   - The original JSON date format: 2016-03-05T00:00:00

   None of these have had any affect
3. All the elements in the datepicker, when it is displayed, have the  'ui-state-disabled' class, which would explain why it doesn't react to mouse clicks to change the date, but not why it is disabled in the first place

**[Edit 2]**
Although it has not changed for at least 12 months, it seems the `data-field="EntriesOpen"`is partly to blame. Removing this tag causes the existing dates to display correctly, and the datepicker to work.

There is, of course, a catch to this. Knockout uses the `data-field` attribute to track which fields have changed. Without this attribute, when I click the button to save the changes, it tells be I have not changed the form, if all I have done is change dates.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `2016-03-18T00:00:00` can be parsed, `05-03-2016 00:00:00` I would think not

Comment: The 05-03-2016 00:00:00 format dates are only displayed, not parsed

Comment: So function niceDate may have an issue. Would that be https://github.com/silvester/jquery.niceDate ?

Comment: No it's not that one. The niceDate script is a locally coded one, that uses moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to return the date in this form: moment(dt).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"); It was incorrectly returning the time (as can be seen from your formatting comment above) but I've now fixed that and it's not making any difference. The date picker is still stuck in June 2021

Comment: I've also tried changing the date to US MM-DD-YYYY format and that's not made any difference either :-(

Comment: I've just noticed all the elements of the datepicker, when it is displayed, has the 'ui-state-disabled' class. Hence the reason it's not doing anything. 

Any ideas what might be causing this? I've looked for, but can't find any 'disabled' calls related to these datepickers.

Comment: is that the jQuery date picker? - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: also what is the dateFormat set up as where you create the datepicker on elements?

Comment: and I believe niceDate should return only the date without time